# ubuntu 16.04 can't input password in command line mode(console mode)

Tags: 16.04, command-line, password, console

In Ubuntu 16.04 I enter control + ALT + F1 into the command line mode(console mode) and after I type my server name, I can't input anything in "Password:" where it goes immediately to the next line. By the way, I have tried to reboot the computer, change the keyboard and switch to the F1 to F6. However, they didn't work. As shown in the picture, as soon as I type the name of my server in the line of "xxx login:" and press the key "Enter", the cursor jumps to the next line of "Password:".
[strange bug in ubuntu command line mode(console mode)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sJDa.jpg)